# VBA: Combining data of multiple files with a master file

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a vba macro for consolidating data entry from individuals' working file to a master file. However, my code is only available to work on one single individual workbook and the master file at the same time, and required to manually renaming the workbooks' name. I am looking for ways to consolidate multiple individuals' workbook to the master file within one macro.

As mentioned, "NEWwb" representing the individual's workbook and "MASTERwb" representing the master file.
How could I modify my code in order to make it works for consolidating multiple individual's file (i.e. repeating the macro to all workbooks within a folder)?

```
Sub CombineExcel_v2()
    Dim MASTERwb As Workbook
    Dim MASTERws As Worksheet
    Dim NEWwb As Workbook
    Dim NEWws As Worksheet
    
    'set workbook and worksheet
    Set MASTERwb = Workbooks("Master")
    Set MASTERws = MASTERwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set NEWwb = Workbooks("New")
    Set NEWws = NEWwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim MASTERrow As Long
    Dim column As Long
    Dim NEWrow As Long
    
    Dim MASTERTrow As Range
    Dim NEWTrow As Range
    
    Dim dtoday As Date
    dtoday = Date
    
    Dim alphaIDColumn As String
    Dim DateColumn As String
    Dim PolicyNoColumn As String
    
    alphaIDColumn = "B"
    DateColumn = "A"
    PolicyNoColumn = "C"
    
    For NEWrow = 2 To 2970
        'if the data is input today, then copy cell
        If CDate(NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, DateColumn).Value) = CDate(dtoday) Then
            For MASTERrow = 2 To 2970
                If MASTERws.Cells(MASTERrow, alphaIDColumn).Value = NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, alphaIDColumn).Value And MASTERws.Cells(MASTERrow, PolicyNoColumn).Value = NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, PolicyNoColumn).Value Then
                    Set MASTERTrow = MASTERws.Rows(MASTERrow)
                    Set NEWTrow = NEWws.Rows(NEWrow)
                    
                    MASTERTrow.Copy
                    
                    NEWTrow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            Next MASTERrow
        End If
    Next NEWrow
    
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+process+all+files+in+a+folder+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop that goes through all the individual workbooks within a folder and combines the data into the master file. Here's a modified version of your code :)

```
Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim MASTERwb As Workbook
    Dim MASTERws As Worksheet
    Dim NEWwb As Workbook
    Dim NEWws As Worksheet
    Dim dtoday As Date
    Dim alphaIDColumn As String
    Dim DateColumn As String
    Dim PolicyNoColumn As String
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    alphaIDColumn = "B"
    DateColumn = "A"
    PolicyNoColumn = "C"
    dtoday = Date
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path 
    
    Set MASTERwb = ThisWorkbook 
    Set MASTERws = MASTERwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Loop through files in the folder
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileName <> "Master.xlsm" Then ' Skip the master xlsm file
            ' Open the individual workbook
            Set NEWwb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & FileName)
            Set NEWws = NEWwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            
            ' Find the last row in the master worksheet
            MASTERrow = MASTERws.Cells(MASTERws.Rows.Count, alphaIDColumn).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Copy data from individual workbook to master workbook
            For NEWrow = 2 To 2970
                If Not IsDate(NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, DateColumn)) Then Exit For
                If DateValue(NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, DateColumn).Value) = CDate(dtoday) Then
                    MASTERrow = MASTERrow + 1
                    For Column = 1 To 3 ' Assuming you want to copy 3 columns
                        MASTERws.Cells(MASTERrow, Column).Value = NEWws.Cells(NEWrow, Column).Value
                    Next Column
                End If
            Next NEWrow
            
            ' Close the individual workbook
            NEWwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next file in the folder
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    Set MASTERws = Nothing
    Set MASTERwb = Nothing
End Sub
```